# Laravel auth user role update

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have a project, I've made, in Laravel. On my admin panel, I can view a list of users and perform CRUD operations, one operation is I can change the role of a user between 'user' and 'admin' with a simple button. Now i don't want the logged in user to be able to downgrade their own privileges as I obviously get an error, as they are then in essence, somewhere they don't belong.

My code for the actual table:

```
@if($users->count() > 0)
     @foreach ($users as $user)
         <tr>
             <td><img src="{{ asset($user->avatar) }}" alt="Avatar" width="45px" height="45px" style="border-radius: 50%"></td>
             <td>{{ $user->firstname }}</td>
             <td>{{ $user->lastname }}</td>
             <td>{{ $user->username }}</td>
             <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
             <td>
                                    @if($user->admin)
                                        <a class="button warning small warnBtn" href="{{ route('user.not.admin',['id' => $user->id]) }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-hand-point-down fa-lg" style="color: white"></i> Make User</a>
                                    @else
                                        <a class="button warning small warnBtn" href="{{ route('user.admin',['id' => $user->id]) }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-success"><i class="fas fa-hand-point-up fa-lg" style="color: white"></i> Make Admin</a>
                                    @endif</td>
                                <td align="center"><a href="{{ route('user.edit', [$user->id]) }}"class="btn.btn-info"><i class="fas fa-edit fa-lg" style="color: green"></i></a></td>
                                <td align="center"><a href="{{ route('user.delete', [$user->id]) }}"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt fa-lg" style="color: red"></i></a></td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    @else
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="8"><h2 align="center">There Are Currently No Users</h2></th>
                        </tr>
                    @endif
```

How would I hide the button, just on the row for the logged in user? I tried:

```
@if($user->admin && !Auth::user())//Show the button
```

Obviously that did exactly what I told it to and fell to the else statement and changed the button, for every admin.

I'm actually quite puzzled here, it's probably the most simple solution, too. If anybody has a tip, that would be great, thank you.

Comment: How can you check who is the logged user?

Comment: Auth::user() isn't it?

Comment: `Auth::user()` checks if the user is logged, right?. You can retrieve more information(not just if is there some user logged)  about the logged user using `Auth`?

Comment: Ignore it. Writing solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare their ids to see if the user of the row is the same as the logged in user.

```
@if($user->admin && $user->id != Auth::user()->id) // Show the button
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually had to wrap my initial @if block in:  @if($user->id != Auth::user()->id) But your code was exactly what I needed, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to compare if the logged user isn't the same of the rendered user inside the `foreach`.

```
@if($user->admin && $user->id != Auth::user()->id) // Show the button
   <a class="button warning small warnBtn" href="{{ route('user.not.admin',['id' => $user->id]) }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">
       <i class="fas fa-hand-point-down fa-lg" style="color: white></i> 
       Make User
   </a>
@else
   [...]
@endif
```

Then, if they're not different, the user won't be able to downgrade his privileges. Have you considered to change these buttons to a Select?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I really appreciate it. I did consider a select, but as a final touch, I'm going to replace the button's action with a confirm modal, just so they are sure what they are actually doing, if they attempt to create a new admin and don't create one, by mistake.